# How to Pivot table on Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I would like to pivot the columns in the original table (Table1) below to produce the desired output on Oracle SQL. Below is the query to create the table.

```sql
CREATE TABLE ReconciliationTable (
RECONCILIATION_DATE DATE,
Account_Name VARCHAR(50),
Currency VARCHAR(3),
Offshore_Account VARCHAR(50),
Offshore_Amount DECIMAL(18, 2),
Offshore_Difference DECIMAL(18, 2),
Ledger_Account VARCHAR(50),
Ledger_Amount DECIMAL(18, 2),
Ledger_Difference DECIMAL(18, 2),
Offshore_Ledger_Difference DECIMAL(18, 2)
);

INSERT INTO ReconciliationTable VALUES 
('2023-10-31', 'Bank1', 'USD', 'Opening Balance', 16019912.00, NULL, 'Opening Balance', 0.00, NULL, 16019912.00),
('2023-10-31', 'Bank1', 'USD', 'Closing Balance', 16019912.00, 0.00, 'Closing Balance', 0.00, 0.00, 16019912.00),
('2023-10-31', 'Bank2', 'CHF', 'Opening Balance', 872864.00, NULL, 'Opening Balance', 0.00, NULL, 872864.00),
('2023-10-31', 'Bank2', 'CHF', 'Closing Balance', 873725.00, 861.00, 'Closing Balance', 0.00, 0.00, 873725.00),
('2023-10-31', 'Bank3', 'CAD', 'Opening Balance', 10831173.00, NULL, 'Opening Balance', 233782136.00, NULL, -222950963.00),
('2023-10-31', 'Bank3', 'CAD', 'Closing Balance', 10842614.00, 11441.00, 'Closing Balance', 233782136.00, 0.00, -222939522.00),
('2023-11-02', 'Bank1', 'USD', 'Opening Balance', 80693853.00, NULL, 'Opening Balance', 3508963518.00, NULL, -3428269665.00),
('2023-11-02', 'Bank1', 'USD', 'Closing Balance', 80772301.00, 78448.00, 'Closing Balance', 3508963518.00, 0.00, -3428191217.00),
('2023-11-02', 'Bank2', 'CHF', 'Opening Balance', 58156966.00, NULL, 'Opening Balance', 149734549.00, NULL, -91577583.00),
('2023-11-02', 'Bank2', 'CHF', 'Closing Balance', 58156966.00, 0.00, 'Closing Balance', 49734549.00, NULL, 0.00, -91577583.00),
('2023-11-02', 'Bank3', 'CAD', 'Opening Balance', 18380423.00, NULL, 'Opening Balance', 489910.00, NULL, 17890513.00),
('2023-11-02', 'Bank3', 'CAD', 'Closing Balance', 18380423.00, 0.00, 'Closing Balance', 489910.00, 0.00, 17890513.00);
```

The 2 values in **'Offshore Account'** become column names **Offshore Opening Balance** and **Offshore Closing Balance**

The 2 values in **'Ledger Account'** become column names **Ledger Opening Balance** and **Ledger Closing Balance**

**Please also note that:**

*Offshore Difference = Offshore Closing Balance - Offshore Opening Balance*

*Ledger Difference = Ledger Closing Balance - Ledger Opening Balance*

*Offshore/Ledger Difference (Opening Balance) = Offshore Opening Balance - Ledger Opening Balance*

*Offshore/Ledger Difference (Closing Balance) = Offshore Closing Balance - Ledger Closing Balance*

**Table1**

| RECONCILIATION_DATE | Account Name | Currency | Offshore Account | Offshore Amount | Offshore Difference | Ledger Account | Ledger Amount | Ledger Difference | Offshore/Ledger Difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 31-Oct-23 | Bank1 | USD | Opening Balance | 16,019,912.00 |  | Opening Balance | 0.00 |  | 16,019,912.00 |
| 31-Oct-23 | Bank1 | USD | Closing Balance | 16,019,912.00 | 0.00 | Closing Balance | 0.00 | 0.00 | 16,019,912.00 |
| 31-Oct-23 | Bank2 | CHF | Opening Balance | 872,864.00 |  | Opening Balance | 0.00 |  | 872,864.00 |
| 31-Oct-23 | Bank2 | CHF | Closing Balance | 873,725.00 | 861.00 | Closing Balance | 0.00 | 0.00 | 873,725.00 |
| 31-Oct-23 | Bank3 | CAD | Opening Balance | 10,831,173.00 |  | Opening Balance | 233,782,136.00 |  | -222,950,963.00 |
| 31-Oct-23 | Bank3 | CAD | Closing Balance | 10,842,614.00 | 11,441.00 | Closing Balance | 233,782,136.00 | 0.00 | -222,939,522.00 |
| 02-Nov-23 | Bank1 | USD | Opening Balance | 80,693,853.00 |  | Opening Balance | 3,508,963,518.00 |  | -3,428,269,665.00 |
| 02-Nov-23 | Bank1 | USD | Closing Balance | 80,772,301.00 | 78,448.00 | Closing Balance | 3,508,963,518.00 | 0.00 | -3,428,191,217.00 |
| 02-Nov-23 | Bank2 | CHF | Opening Balance | 58,156,966.00 |  | Opening Balance | 149,734,549.00 |  | -91,577,583.00 |
| 02-Nov-23 | Bank2 | CHF | Closing Balance | 58,156,966.00 | 0.00 | Closing Balance | 49,734,549.00 |  | 0.00 |
| 02-Nov-23 | Bank3 | CAD | Opening Balance | 18,380,423.00 |  | Opening Balance | 489,910.00 |  | 17,890,513.00 |
| 02-Nov-23 | Bank3 | CAD | Closing Balance | 18,380,423.00 | 0.00 | Closing Balance | 489,910.00 | 0.00 | 17,890,513.00 |

**Desired Output:**

| RECONCILIATION_DATE | Account Name | Currency | Offshore Opening Balance | Offshore Closing Balance | Offshore Difference | Ledger Opening Balance | Ledger Closing Balance | Ledger Difference | Offshore/Ledger Difference (Opening Balance) | Offshore/Ledger Difference (Closing Balance) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 31-Oct-23 | Bank1 | USD | 16,019,912.00 | 16,019,912.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 16,019,912.00 | 16,019,912.00 |
| 31-Oct-23 | Bank2 | CHF | 872,864.00 | 873,725.00 | 861.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 872,864.00 | 873,725.00 |
| 31-Oct-23 | Bank3 | CAD | 10,831,173.00 | 10,842,614.00 | 11,441.00 | 233,782,136.00 | 233,782,136.00 | 0.00 | -222,950,963.00 | -222,939,522.00 |
| 02-Nov-23 | Bank1 | USD | 80,693,853.00 | 80,772,301.00 | 78,448.00 | 3,508,963,518.00 | 3,508,963,518.00 | 0.00 | -3,428,269,665.00 | -3,428,191,217.00 |
| 02-Nov-23 | Bank2 | CHF | 58,156,966.00 | 58,156,966.00 | 0.00 | 149,734,549.00 | 149,734,549.00 | 0.00 | -91,577,583.00 | -91,577,583.00 |
| 02-Nov-23 | Bank3 | CAD | 18,380,423.00 | 18,380,423.00 | 0.00 | 489,910.00 | 489,910.00 | 0.00 | 17,890,513.00 | 17,890,513.00 |

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data (that we can copy-paste and execute and not data as a table that we have to reformat into something usable); **YOUR** attempt at a solution; and the issues/errors with **YOUR** solution.

Comment: @MT0 Thank you for explaining, does the edit help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve the desired output, you can use the Oracle SQL `CASE` statement to pivot the columns and calculate the differences. Here's a query that should help you achieve this:

```sql
SELECT
    RECONCILIATION_DATE,
    "Account Name",
    Currency,
    MAX(CASE WHEN "Offshore Account" = 'Opening Balance' THEN "Offshore Amount" END) AS "Offshore Opening Balance",
    MAX(CASE WHEN "Offshore Account" = 'Closing Balance' THEN "Offshore Amount" END) AS "Offshore Closing Balance",
    MAX(CASE WHEN "Offshore Account" = 'Closing Balance' THEN "Offshore Amount" END) -
    MAX(CASE WHEN "Offshore Account" = 'Opening Balance' THEN "Offshore Amount" END) AS "Offshore Difference",
    MAX(CASE WHEN "Ledger Account" = 'Opening Balance' THEN "Ledger Amount" END) AS "Ledger Opening Balance",
    MAX(CASE WHEN "Ledger Account" = 'Closing Balance' THEN "Ledger Amount" END) AS "Ledger Closing Balance",
    MAX(CASE WHEN "Ledger Account" = 'Closing Balance' THEN "Ledger Amount" END) -
    MAX(CASE WHEN "Ledger Account" = 'Opening Balance' THEN "Ledger Amount" END) AS "Ledger Difference",
    MAX(CASE WHEN "Offshore Account" = 'Opening Balance' THEN "Offshore Amount" END) -
    MAX(CASE WHEN "Ledger Account" = 'Opening Balance' THEN "Ledger Amount" END) AS "Offshore/Ledger Difference (Opening Balance)",
    MAX(CASE WHEN "Offshore Account" = 'Closing Balance' THEN "Offshore Amount" END) -
    MAX(CASE WHEN "Ledger Account" = 'Closing Balance' THEN "Ledger Amount" END) AS "Offshore/Ledger Difference (Closing Balance)"
FROM
    Table1
GROUP BY
    RECONCILIATION_DATE, "Account Name", Currency;
```

This query uses the `CASE` statement to conditionally aggregate the values based on the conditions you provided. The `MAX` function is used to handle the aggregation, and the `GROUP BY` clause is used to group the results by the specified columns.

Please note that the column names in the query are enclosed in double quotes (`"`) to handle case sensitivity and spaces in column names. If your column names are case-insensitive or don't contain spaces, you can omit the double quotes.

Feel free to adjust the query based on your specific database setup and column naming conventions.

Another way to achieve the desired output is by using the `PIVOT` clause. Here's a simplified query using `PIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT
    RECONCILIATION_DATE,
    "Account Name",
    Currency,
    "Opening Balance" AS "Offshore Opening Balance",
    "Closing Balance" AS "Offshore Closing Balance",
    "Closing Balance" - "Opening Balance" AS "Offshore Difference",
    "Ledger Opening Balance",
    "Ledger Closing Balance",
    "Ledger Closing Balance" - "Ledger Opening Balance" AS "Ledger Difference",
    "Offshore Opening Balance" - "Ledger Opening Balance" AS "Offshore/Ledger Difference (Opening Balance)",
    "Offshore Closing Balance" - "Ledger Closing Balance" AS "Offshore/Ledger Difference (Closing Balance)"
FROM (
    SELECT
        RECONCILIATION_DATE,
        "Account Name",
        Currency,
        "Offshore Account",
        "Offshore Amount",
        "Ledger Account",
        "Ledger Amount"
    FROM Table1
)
PIVOT (
    MAX("Offshore Amount") AS Offshore,
    MAX("Ledger Amount") AS Ledger
    FOR ("Offshore Account", "Ledger Account") IN (
        ('Opening Balance' AS "Opening Balance", 'Closing Balance' AS "Closing Balance")
    )
);
```

In this query:

- The inner query selects the relevant columns from your original table.
- The `PIVOT` clause then pivots the data based on the specified columns ('Offshore Account' and 'Ledger Account') and their values ('Opening Balance' and 'Closing Balance').
- Finally, the outer query performs the necessary calculations to get the desired output.

This approach simplifies the syntax by directly using the `PIVOT` clause to transform the data. Adjust the column names as needed based on your actual database setup.

Comment: Thank you Justin! This has solved my problem!